# Linux bluetooth serial can only be opened once

Tags: linux, serial-port, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth serial port and am trying to connect to it.  I do:

```
sudo rfcomm bind 13 00:0A:3A:26:4A:86
```

and that seems to succeed.  I then try to access it:

```
>>> f=file('/dev/rfcomm13','rw')
>>> f.close()
>>> f=file('/dev/rfcomm13','rw')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/rfcomm13'
```

This seems to be consistent -- it can be opened *once*, but ever afterwards it is "busy" until I unbind and rebind it.  Doing this in python shows the error most clearly, but it seems to happen everywhere.

It seems that the close syscall isn't cleaning up some key resource.  From a quick skim of the driver source, it's probably a dlci channel or something similar, but I'm pretty vague on what those are.

Is there any way to open the connection multiple times per bind?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just run the `rfcomm` command again? If I understand correctly, when you run it it creates `/dev/rfcomm13`, when you close it that `/dev` file will be removed, and you will have to run `rfcomm` again.

Comment: @terdon If I could I'd just do that.  I need to use libraries with multiple opens and closes.  I wouldn't expect closing a dev file to remove it, though -- that's not the normal /dev behavior.

Comment: That was just a shot in the dark, I have absolutely no experience with what you're trying. It just occurred to me that perhaps the `f.close()` is the issue.

Comment: This still seems to be the case.  @terdon it doesn't seem to have anything to do with Python, so it's probably not `f.close()` that's at fault.  Using screen to open the same rfcomm device multiple times shows the same problem.